# How to edit a cell value in datagridview and save

Tags: vb.net

I want to edit the value of my cell that is already in my database and save it.

just for example the original value in cell in the dataGridview is arrived but in the end i want to change it to released

Comment: With DataGridView1
            .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter

            DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(0).Value = dr(0)

        End With

        str = "update customer set consignee" = dr(1)
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    End Sub

Comment: this is my code bro... i want to edit the item value in every cell in data gridview and update it

Answer (score 0):

I think you Need to explain it a little more, but maby this helps:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(0).Value = "released"
```

This changes the value of cell in row 2 and column 1 to released.

Best regards.